# How long is a creature Fascinated by Hypnotic Pattern?

Tags: spells, duration, pathfinder-2e

[Hypnotic Pattern](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=157) says that upon one of several triggers, an affected creature makes a Will save, and if it fails, it becomes Fascinated. No duration, just Fascinated. Is that until it leaves the pattern? For the Pattern's duration? As long as it can see the pattern? As long as it continues to do one of the things that trigger a Will save?

Answer (score 8):

It will last until one of these two conditions are met:

- The duration of [Hypnotic Pattern](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=157) expires:

  > Duration sustained **up to 1 minute**
- Or if you or your allies take a hostile action against a [fascinated](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=14) creature:

  > This condition ends if a creature uses hostile actions against you or any of your allies.

Comment: Just to clarify: even if the creature were to run around a corner so that it can no longer see the pattern, it would still remain fascinated by it until one of those conditions are met?

Comment: *"Creatures are dazzled while inside the pattern."*

Comment: The fascination is in addition to that.

Comment: So it would cease being both fascinated and dazzled if it left the pattern?